# What are some reliable ways to parse out a house name/number from a street address for use in Address Verification System (AVS)

Tags: e-commerce, payment, adyen

I am using Adyen's [custom card integration](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/cards/custom-card-integration) to build a payment form. I would like to collect the user's billing address and pass it along to Adyen's [Address Verification System](https://docs.adyen.com/risk-management/avs-checks#avs-for-ecommerce).

According to that documentation, AVS expects to receive the billing address as an object with separate keys for the `houseNumberOrName` and `street`. However, I would like my front-end to have a form where users write their address with the house number/name and street in a combined input. I do not want to have a separate input for the house number. I feel that it is more customary, at least according to my experience. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve, visually:

[A payment form where the house number and street name are written in one input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFkbQ.png)

Therefore I would like to have a reliable way to parse out the house number/name from the street name. To me this seems like a task more complicated than I personally could handle with regular expressions, because there are many different formats of addresses. I have tried a basic regular expression implementation to parse out the house number, which worked for addresses that I might consider to be "normal". But I could not think of a reliable regex pattern to match house *names* which seem much more freeform — not to mention some countries use street address formats that I might not be aware of.

```
# number + street name
123 Main St

# number with letter suffix
123A Main St

# street name featuring numbers
123 E 42nd St

# house number comes after street name
Rosenthalerstr. 12

# named house which has no house number nor street name
House of McGee
```

I am curious if anyone in the community is willing to share an implementation that they think was successful. I can't really think of any solutions to this problem beyond using a third party API like Google's Address Validation, which I'd rather avoid in order to save money.

If nothing else, I know I can just amend my design to have a separate inputs for house number/name and street name. Still I'd like to give this is a shot!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Geoapify (https://apidocs.geoapify.com/) has a free plan, there are also some NPM packages (if you need for example only US addresses), but honestly, given the goal to use Adyen AVS, I would consider changing the form (unless you can rely on a robust solution like Google API or similar).